# Confirmation of oil change bolt on a Ford Focus

Tags: ford, oil-change

I'm prepping an engine oil change on a 2014 Ford Focus,
and would like to confirm if the 15mm bolt shown in the picture is the one I have to remove to release the oil.

Is the correct one identified?

[image: Picture depicting where I think the oil change bolt is]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be the one. For reference, here is what the oil pan should look like from the side for the 2.0L naturally aspirated engine (I'm assuming that's what you have):

[image]

And this definitely looks like the side you're showing:

[image]